# String Comparison in Shell

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to compare Current month which i got from date utility with the user input. Even when I am giving Oct as input its giving incorrect result.

```
read -r month
current=`date +”%b”`
echo $current
if [ "$month" = "$current" ];
then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "no "
fi
```

I am not able to understand why its always giving no as output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using a non-ascii editor to create your script, you should switch to an ascii/utf8 one and use the regular quotes ( `"` ) and not the other ones ( `”` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running your code and inputting `Oct` at the prompt you get:

```
Oct         # this is what you input at the prompt
”Oct”       # this is what your input is compared against
no          # this is the result of the comparison: not true
```

Evidently, if you inputted `”Oct”` the comparison would be true:

```
”Oct”
”Oct”
match
```

If you don't want to type the two [closing double quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html), just remove them from the comparison string:

```
read -r month
current=`date +%b`
echo $current
if [ "$month" = "$current" ];
then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "no "
fi
```

This way, you can just type `Oct` and it will match `Oct`:

```
Oct
Oct
match
```

---

If you want to further develop your program, the next step could be to make the comparison case-insensitive: this way your users could type `oct`, `Oct` or `OCT` without caring for the proper case.

Answer (score 2):

There's one very obvious error in your code.

They are the quotation marks around the date format

```
current=`date +”%b”`
```

vs

```
current=`date +"%b"` # this is the one you should be using
```

Comment: So i need to remove quotation from the date & then compare, right?

Comment: +1 because you addressed the quotation marks issue. However I think [there's nothing wrong in comparison with `=`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168288/108618).

Comment: `[ "$month" = "$current" ]` is perfectly fine and arguably more correct than `[ "$month" == "$current" ]` because [the former is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and the latter isn't. Run `dash -c '[ a == a ]] && echo yes'` for example. `=` vs `==` is a C-like problem, `[`s `=` and `==` are usually equivalent where both are supported.

Comment: (Argh, typo in my example! The `]]` should be `]`.)

Comment: @muru is right: use  `if [ "$month" = "$current" ];` . Do not use the == . The problem came from the fact that OP added 2 extra characters: `”` to $current, hence the 2 dates couldn't be equal.